# Global Seed for Multiple Numpy Imports

Tags: python, numpy, random

Assume that I have a Python project structure as:

> `main.py` which imports `random_initialization.py`
>
> `main.py` which imports `sample_around_solution.py`

Both `random_initialization` and `sample_around_solution.py` import `numpy`.

Now, 
`random_initialization` starts a random instance of a problem, `main` runs a algorithm and `sample_around_solution` uses random samples around the solution to compute some metric (quality of solution, say).

**I want replicability of the runs** for which I have `numpy.random.seed(0)` in both imported files. Is this the right way to do this? I feel there might be some edge case where this is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a good idea never to have anything manipulate the random seed, except for the topmost module, which will typically be either

- a short `main.py` that just `import`s, does some program options and configs, and calls other stuff)
- a `unittest`

The single-point for seeding allows doing some useful stuff, e.g.,

- you can control setting the seed for reproducibility (as you write).
- you can control varying the seed for better coverage (e.g., if you will run the sub-modules through unit tests).
- you can store the seed in persistent storage, so that if some execution has a problem, you can reproduce it.

Conversely, if the submodules do the seeding themselves, you can't. I also think this is wrong encapsulation: instead of a module that does some well-defined functionality X, it does X + seeding.

---

Incidentally, I wrote a couple of years ago a [tiny library on PyPI - UnittestRandGenState](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/UnittestRandGenState/) for doing "smart" seedings for `unittest`, and gave it some thought then. It basically relies on the absence of what you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have each component of a simulation use its own random number generator. If each Monte Carlo component has its own module, and you want a global rng state for the module, then you could put an initialization function in the module:

```
def init_rng(seed):
    global rng
    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(seed=seed)
```

Then you can set up and control each process independently, i.e

```
import componentA
import componentB
import componentC

componentA.init_rng(0)
componentB.init_rng(1)
componentC.init_rng(2)
```

If you don't like globals, you can also have your stochastic processes encapsulated in classes with rng attributes and initialization functions.

If all processes are sharing the same generator, then the outcome of processA may depend on how may numbers processB generated, etc...